# How to improve heat distribution of enclosed log burner

Tags: heat

I have seen fans that sit on top of log burners to help distribute the heat of a log fire.

My log fire is enclosed (built in with marble above) like the middle pic on the bottom row of this screenshot, although all 3 of the bottom row images have the same issue.

[image]

Given that it looks like these fans are not supposed to be in the burner, how would I make the heat distribution more effective? (my question is not how do I use these fans... The fan is included to demonstrate the outcome I am after)

Comment: Please edit inti your question the model number of the fan whose picture you posted. This will also provide a source for that picture, which is a requirement on this site.

Comment: They use the rising heat to turn the fan, so they become a paper weight if put on a table.  You might need a powered fan to move the air around.

Comment: Shame that it doesn't have an integrated fan like mine does. Are you sure it doesn't have facilities for that? Seems silly that anyone would even build one without these days.

Answer (score 2):

All the fans of this style that I have seen (my sister has two, one on each of her woodstoves) have a small electric motor to drive the fan.

The power to drive the electric motor comes from a Peltier module that has one side heated by indirect contact with the hot woodstove surface and the other side cooled by the, usually elaborate, heat sink behind the fan.

The positioning suggested is to help limit the temperature the base of the fan is subjected to.

as for use on a wood burner with lots of thermal mass, then the fan may not turn due to the lower temperature of the surface.

Answer (score 1):

The picture seems to show a heat-driven fan system. There's a flare of metal fingers behind the fan blade, which looks like a "heat sink" commonly used in electronics.

I deduce that the heat rising from the metal stove top goes up through the leg of the fan and out through the heat sink, or rises through the air and into and through the heat sink. The "motor" of the fan is designed to use this rising heat to turn the fan blades and drive air through the heat sink, making the moving air warmer and pushing it into the room.

The three "don't do this" pictures show places where the fan body won't pick up much heat, and then the blades won't turn. The fan is below the heat output of the fireplace (left), it is insulated by the fireplace mantle marble (center), and the fireplace case is thermally protected (right). Indication that rising heat is needed is given by the center picture caption not to use the fan on a tabletop "low-temperature" furnace.

You'll need a different fan to move heat around in your situation, perhaps a plug-in fan. Maybe the manufacturer of the stove has an add-on. Or merely circulating air in the room, to force a current so the hot air at the ceiling gets moved down to where the humans tend to be. A slow-speed reverse-running ceiling fan does an awesome job at this.

Answer (score 1):

This type of fan is not suitable for a built-in fireplace, since it needs to sit on a hot surface. *Any table fan* pointed at a built-in fireplace is useless and dangerous, since it will blow smoke and possibly carbon monoxide into the home.

Some built-in fireplaces are designed with built-in air channels in the masonry that promote warm air circulation in the room. A plain built-in fireplace without any kind of heat recovery design is the least efficient way to burn wood, since it can only warm the room by radiant heat. Almost all the heat produced by burning wood goes up the chimney and is lost. The draft up the chimney also creates a negative pressure in the house, which causes it to suck cold air into the house through any cracks and around loose doors and windows.

The one way that you can recover some of the heat that's currently going up the chimney without major reconstruction is by using a fireplace heat exchanger like this:

[image: e]

You build your fire within the cradle and the pipes get hot. Cold room air is sucked in the bottom openings of the pipes, it warms up within the pipes and it shoots out the top of the pipes into the room. So you continue to get radiant heat plus you get some convective heat. Powered versions are also available. Google "fireplace heat exchanger" for more info.

Photo credit: craigslist.com